# Trouble 'Pip' downloading specific Python module

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pip

I am trying to pip download a `.whl` file with dependencies for a specific python implementation `cp35` but cannot get it to work.

Working on kit `Linux 4096cc36f7af 4.9.93-linuxkit-aufs #1 SMP Wed Jun 6 16:55:56 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

**Command:**

`pip download --only-binary=:all: --platform linux_x86_64 --python-version 35 --implementation cp numpy`

**Response is:**

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions: )
>   No matching distribution found for numpy

If I run the command:

```
pip download --only-binary=:all:  numpy
```

The I get the file `numpy-1.15.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl`

How can I get the cp35 version or am I mis-understanding this completely?

Comment: To be honest, I've always found that particular workflow (downloading a wheel for another version/architecture) very fiddly. You can just find the wheel over at https://pypi.org/project/numpy/#files instead... Not posting this as an answer, because it doesn't answer your specific question. :)

Comment: Typical, as I posted figured it out: pip download -only-binary=:all: --platform manylinux1_x86_64 --python-version 35 --implementation cp --abi cp35m numpy

Comment: Feel free to post a self-answer!

Answer (score 2):

```
pip download -only-binary=:all: --platform manylinux1_x86_64 --python-version 35 --implementation cp --abi cp35m numpy
```

The platform and the abi version were the issue which you can find out by looking at the #files list.

http://pypi.org/project/numpy/#files